# Angular 4 - make component more reusable

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to make my component more reusable. In the component I'm binding two values with ngModel: elem.key and elem.value. The problem is that wherever I want to use this component, the element has to have key and value properties, for example some data from Api might have name, and nickname etc. For now I can use my component repeatedly, but only if the values of object are key and value. My code:

html:

```
<button (click)="addNew()">Add</button>
        <div *ngFor="let elem of elements">
          <text-input [(ngModel)]="elem.key" type="text"></text-input>
          <text-input [(ngModel)]="elem.value" type="text"></text-input>
        </div>
```

ts:

```
@Input() elements: any[];

  addNew() {
    this.elements.push({
      key: '',
      value: ''
      });
    }
```

If I use my component in another:

```
        <input-key-value [elements]="values">
```

It works fine if I only need to add to values array {key: '', value: ''} But sometimes I want to add for example {name: '', nickname: ''}, cause data in this format must be sent to the server.

I tried add another Input name inputs, {key: 'name', value: 'name'} And in html:

```
      <text-input [(ngModel)]="elem[inputs.key]" type="text"></text-input>
      <text-input [(ngModel)]="elem.[inputs.value]" type="text"></text-input>
```

But this is again pushing wrong data to my main array.

Comment: what do you mean by "But this is again pushing wrong data to my main array."?

Comment: and try to have your component as well

Comment: For example: I want to push to array: {name: '', nickname: ''}, but my function from input-key-value component always pushing {key: '', value: ''}. But i want to pushing different key elements to my object, one time key: '', another name: '' etc.

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: I have updated my answer, check it now. I have mentioned view and component as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me.

input-key-value template:

```
<div *ngFor="let elem of elements">
  <div *ngFor="let prop of keys(elem)" >
    <text-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="elem[prop]"></text-input>
  </div>
</div>
```

input-key-value ts:

```
keys(element) {
    return Object.keys(element);
}
```

Depending on how many properties your object has, it renders as much text boxes. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

In your add new function you might need to do like below

```
@Input() elements: any[];
@Input() elementKey: string = 'key';
@Input() elementValue: string = 'value';
addNewe() {
    const element = {};
    element[this.elementKey] = '';
    element[this.elementValue] = '';
    this.elements.push(element);
}
```

and in your view, you should do like below

```
<button (click)="addNew()">Add</button>
<div *ngFor="let elem of elements">
    <text-input [(ngModel)]="elem[elementKey]"
        type="text"></text-input>
    <text-input [(ngModel)]="elem[elementValue]"
        type="text"></text-input>
</div>
```

you might need to pass element key and element values when when you are using this component

when you are using your component. If you have to pass key and value like below, based on example that you have provided in comment {name: '', nickname: ''}

```
<input-key-value [elements]="values" [elementKey]='name' [elementValue]='nickname'>
```

If you are passing elements like {key: '', value: ''} then there is no requirment to pass element key and element value inputs. you can directly use it

```
<input-key-value [elements]="values">
```

Comment: I don't think this is in accordance with what the OP asked for.

Comment: @LloydFrancis i didnt mentioned complete code before, I have updated my answer and now you can see, that we can have dynamic object with custom properties

Comment: I still think we can make it more generic, rather than hardcoding 'name' and 'nickname', so that it can be reused better.

Comment: hmm, Yes i agree with you but for now this will serve his purpose, He can pass what every key & values he want  :)

Comment: Yeah, agreed. It will only be a problem if he does not know ahead of time what the `elements` array will contain.