# Is there a way to make my components fully reusable in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I created a simple component to display a list of buttons using the ngFor directive.

Here is a simplified version of what the component looks like : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eezqjv

The data will be eventually fetched from an api through a service component and I'm wondering if there is a way to reuse this list component I created with different data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this post helped me make my component reusable 
[Angular 4 - make component more reusable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497616/angular-4-make-component-more-reusable)

I placed the @Input() decorator followed by only instantiating the variable of type Tile (the interface I created) in the .ts file and I moved the data from there to the file that is using the component. 
When I placed my custom component in the html template file, I bound the data using the square brackets notation from the component.ts to the component.html